# Custom UITableViewCell ui outlets nil in TESTS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view

So I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, nothing major here. I subclassed it and added some outlets to it. These outlets are not `nil` when I run the main target. But they are `nil` when I run the test target.

I want to test my custom `UITableViewCell`. So I am creating it in my test class here:

```
    customTableViewControllerCell = CustomTableViewControllerCell()
    customTableViewControllerCell?.setNeedsLayout()
    customTableViewControllerCell?.setNeedsDisplay()
    customTableViewControllerCell?.layoutIfNeeded()
    customTableViewControllerCell?.layoutSubviews()
```

As you can see I am really trying to load the cell's view and it's subviews. I am loading them so I can configure them and then test that they are configured. But when I run my test and the code above gets executed, the custom cell's outlets are `nil`. How do I load the cell's view in my test?

Comment: In what context is your test running?

Comment: They are nil because you are not loading the cell view

Comment: Just create the cell as you did in cellforrow like let customTableViewControllerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdendifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as?CustomTableViewControllerCell